# Proving that division in the multivariable chain rule is "allowed"

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have always had an issue with how one seems to be able to multiply through by say $dx$, which shouldn't be really allowed as $dy/dx$ is really $d/dx$ operating on y. I would like to rigioursly prove that starting from

$$
dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy
$$
we can get to
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.
$$
My approach: Integrate both sides along some path to get
$$F=\int_{\gamma}^{} dF= \int_{\gamma_{x} } \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx + \int_{\gamma_{y} } \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy  .$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}= \lim_{\delta \theta   \to 0 } (?) .$$

I can't seem to formulate taking the limit of this expression (how do I treat the differentials?). If anybody can help me understand this I would greatly appreciate it. Also if anybody has a rigorous proof somewhere I would really appreciate a reference.

Comment: What are $F$ and $f$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Apologies, they should all be $F$